# Numbering rows of a data matrix

Tags: sas

I am using SAS, but if you answer my question in R or with a general algorithm, I can manage. I have a dataset, in which the first 4 rows are for "day 1", the next 4 rows are "day 2", and so forth, until day 5 (short file, but if it will be long, i will need your answer). I with for every day, which includes 4 rows, to add a new column, a new variable, in which the first 2 rows are "1" and the last two rows are "2". So in my case, rows 1,2,5,6,9,10,13,14,17,18 are coded 1, and the others 2. I can do it manually, but if my file will get larger, it won't work. How would you do it ? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are going to group by 4 records, you can take the observation number of each of the record and can divide it by 4.

All possible values will end with  .25, .50, .75 or .00.

So, you can use scan() function later on to get the decimal value alone.

If it is 25 or 50 assign 1 else assign 2.

Hope it helps.

Comment: or use the `MOD` function to return the remainder when dividing by 4 (will have values 0,1,2,3)

Answer (score 0):

In SAS you could use a DO loop around the SET statement to let you generate any pattern you want.  So to add a new variable called `NEW_VAR` whose value will be the repeating sequence `1,1,2,2` you could use code like this:

```
data want ;
   do new_var=1,1,2,2 ;
     set have;
     output;
   end;
run;
```